# Why does first parameter in x86 assembly starts from offset 8?

Tags: assembly, x86, stdcall

I'm trying to develop understanding of Assembly language. I understand that when function creates stack frame, it pushes current `EBP`, than copies stack pointer value to the `EBP`. First (and only) function parameter is accessed by `EBP + 8`. But why 8? Next value after pushed `EBP` is logically offset 4. I read many webpages, but it seems I don't understand this part.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "missing" DWORD is the return address. The call stack looks like:

```
ebp     : saved ebp
ebp + 4 : return address
ebp + 8 : pushed parameter
```

And then if the function uses local variables, since stack space is (typically) reserved for those after the stack frame, they are referenced as `ebp - xx`:

```
ebp - 8 : second local
ebp - 4 : first local
ebp     : saved ebp
ebp + 4 : return address
ebp + 8 : pushed parameter
```

Comment: Thank you. I focused on the wrong part (read about calling conventions, but forgot basic thing)

Comment: Is worth mentioning that the stack in this question grows downward that's why you substrate local variables from ebp which were pushed after arguments and return address.